# Strange Output from Java Server - Has my site been hacked, somehow?

Tags: java, html, webserver

I'm working through building a server in Java, following along with Horstmann's *Big Java*. When I finished a program that "simply establishes a connection to the host, sends a `GET` command to the host, and then receives input from the server until the server closes its connection," I decided to try it on my own website.

The code that it returned looked *nothing* like [what the html on my site looks like](http://thelinell.com). In fact, it looks like something that's completely and totally hijacked my site. Of course, the site itself still looks just like always...

I'm really not sure what I am seeing here. I've double checked that the code is correct. Is the issue on the Java side, or is something off on my side?

Here is the Java:

```
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class WebGet {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        // Get command-line arguments
        String host;
        String resource;

    if (args.length == 2) {
        host = args[0];
        resource = args[1];
    } else {
        System.out.println("Getting / from thelinell.com");
        host = "thelinell.com";
        resource = "/";
    }

    // Open Socket
    final int HTTP_PORT = 80;
    Socket s = new Socket(host, HTTP_PORT);
    // Get Streams
    InputStream instream = s.getInputStream();
    OutputStream outstream = s.getOutputStream();
    // Turn streams into scanners and writers
    Scanner in = new Scanner(instream);
    PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(outstream);
    // Send command
    String command = "GET " + resource + "HTTP/1.1\n" + "Host: " + host + "\n\n";
    out.print(command);
    out.flush();
    // Read server response
    while (in.hasNextLine()) {
        String input = in.nextLine();
        System.out.println(input);
    }

    // Close the socket
    s.close();
}
}
```

Now, the code that is returning looks like a bunch of advertisements and is rather long. Here is a [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/NzTkqCNY) of what it's giving me, for brevity. I will add it here if requested.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need a space in-between the resource URI and the HTTP version fragment:

```
String command = "GET " + resource + "HTTP/1.1\n" ...
```

Should be:

```
String command = "GET " + resource + " HTTP/1.1\n" ...
```

As it is now, your request looks like this:

> GET /HTTP/1.1
>   Host: thelinell.com

Which though not valid for HTTP 1.1, is still being intercepted by your web hosting provider (probably as a [Simple-Request](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/HTTP/1.0/draft-ietf-http-spec.html#Request)), which then spits back that (heinous) collection of banner ads.

Comment: Actually, it's a valid request, it's a [Simple-Request](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/HTTP/1.0/draft-ietf-http-spec.html#Request) (at least the first line, the second is ignored), that will try to get `/HTTP/1.1` from the server's default domain.